# HTML Table Header widths seem to be sizing according to proportional width?

Tags: html

Ok, please bear with me in explaining this. In the code below i have some fake data values. The ACTUAL width on the screen seems to change if i add a couple more characters, rather than be fixed like i have stated 150px. I need the width to be fixed. Is there a property i can set to ensure this?

```
<div id='DataTable' style='height:300px;overflow:auto;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:scroll;width:900px;'  onmouseup="MatchScroll('DataTable','HeaderTable', true);" onmousemove="MatchScroll('DataTable','HeaderTable', false);"     >
<table border='1' style='width:2850px;'>
    <tbody id='ClearDetails'>
        <tr id='Row0'    style='color:black;height:auto;'>
            <td style='width:150px;'>testtttt</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>te</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>t</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>testtttttt</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
            <td style='width:150px;'>test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The overflow property isn't inherited by default, you'd need to use this:

```
<th style='width:150px; overflow-x:hidden;'>
    <a style='width:150px;' href=''>t</a>
</th>
```

Also, I strongly suggest that you use classes.

Comment: I seemed to get it working by including display:block in the href tags. The only problem is that the data (which doesnt have href tags) needs to be of fixed width now.

Comment: If you look at your code, it doesn't make much sense at all.
First you have div with maximum width 900px. Then you have a table with maximum width 2850px ad in it a bunch of columns 150px each. Make up your mind :-)
And fyi, table should have a `<tbody>` and you shouldn't make <a> `display:block`, because it won't work the same in all browsers..